# md-ink-ripple on parent should not be triggered by child

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Is it possible to disable `md-ink-ripple` on a parent element, when I click on a child element like an `<md-checkbox>`?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QKwkOB

```
<md-card md-ink-ripple layout-align="center center">
    <md-checkbox>
        Test
    </md-checkbox>
</md-card>
```

When I click the `<md-checkbox>`, it should not trigger the `md-ink-ripple`, since it has an action attached to it (it's a checkbox). It should still trigger `md-ink-ripple` if I click on text (which isn't the checkbox).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/VKYVBd)

I noticed that the ripple effect starts at mouse down, so one can stop that propagating on the `md-checkbox`.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-app="MyApp" layout="row" layout-align="center center" id="main">
  <md-card md-ink-ripple layout-align="center center">
    <div layout="row" layout-align="start center">
      <md-checkbox ng-mousedown="checkBoxMouseDown($event)">
      </md-checkbox>
      Clicking this should not md-ink-ripple my parent md-card
    </div>
    </md-card>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial']).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.checkBoxMouseDown = function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that's why! I tried `ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()` on the checkbox, but I guess `ng-click` is triggered on mouseup. That explains it. Thanks!

Comment: @Snorlax Glad to be of help. Just wanted to point out that any text within the `md-checkbox` tag will behave in the same way as the checkbox, that's why I moved it out.

Comment: Yeah that is expected behavior. The text should always be inside the checkbox :)